# Index.html not found in Cordova #SalesforceHybridRemoteApps

Tags: salesforce-sdk-hybrid

I followed the steps necessary for creating a hybrid remote app in Cordova. But once I build and run the emulator I am getting error `index.html is missing`.

1. Cordova create xxxx
2. cd xxxx
3. forcedroid create
4. fill in all the remaining things
5. change bootconfig.json file with connected app value etc .
6. build and run emulator from cmd prompt.

I know this is the default page for all Cordova apps but when I create a forcedroid app index.html is getting removed I guess.

Can someone please help?

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Comment: Yah. i created a folder with correct values and den used that folder as target directory. everything seems to be fine. but the problem is "now i am getting error as "unfortunately your app has been stopped"

Comment: created a folder with correct values means? Can you please tell me the changes that you made.